# how to append new component in reactjs not being bundled

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and had been through some examples: [flux-todo-mvc](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc/).
Since react keeps component in a tree structure and updates on state change.

How can I add a new child component (not bundled) at specific node of tree without page refresh?

**More Description**

Suppose component `X` can have three types of child: `A`, `B` and `C`. At first GET request it is always `A` so `X -> A` is rendered and to make it fast we did not include `B` and `C`. For example:

```
X = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <A />
        );
    }
});
React.render( <X />, document.getElementById('_x') );
```

After this, with some change in state can we change child of `X` to `B` or `C` using AJAX request

Comment: This is an optimization that makes sense much further down the road, just do the simplest thing for now and bundle all of them... it'll also perform better while running.  Loading code on demand is always complicated in JS.

Comment: Ya, I do think so. But asking here for some authentic answer for absence of this feature. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Adding another thought in "bundling all of them", facebook updates it's entire Page DOM( minus Navigation Bar) when clicking Profile page and only middle column while clicking any group page. Is it all there server sending partial page when made Ajax Request? Please share your idea of possible ways.

Answer (score 4):

You can write conditional logic inside your render function to set a variable to null or a component instance. And inject that inside the returned render JSX.

Such as:

```
render: function() {
  var subComponent = null;
  if (this.state.showSub) {
    subComponent = <Child />;
  }
  return (
    <div>{subComponent}</div>
  );
}
```

Only way to do it with state changes in real time. Can't update the render code in real time without an actual refresh.

Comment: Hi @agmcleod , I was confused whether you got my question correctly so I updated it again. Please reply, if this is your real answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
render: function() {
  var child = function(){
      if(this.state.ajax_result ==1) {return <B/>
      else if(this.state.ajax_result ==2) {return <C/>}
      else {return <A/>}
  }


return ( {child} );
}
```

now outside of render, listen to your ajax calls. every time the state will change, your component will re-render